How can i fix this error on my code sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
in function edit() the row variable in sql (...WHERE playerID = %s, id)
what can i type in order to assign playerID with id
def display():
    records = c.execute("SELECT * FROM MyPlayers")
    global i
    i = 0
    for player in records:
        for j in range(len(player)):
            playerLabel = Label(playerFrame, width=10, bg='#ffd6e7',fg='black', text=player[j], borderwidth=0)
            playerLabel.grid(row=i, column=j)
            editButton = Button(playerFrame, width=3,bg='#ffd6e7', text="Edit", relief='ridge', anchor='w', command=lambda k=player[0]: edit(k))
            editButton.grid(row=i, column=7, padx=2, pady=1)
            viewButton = Button(playerFrame, text="View Stats", width=8,bg='#ffd6e7', relief='ridge', anchor='w')
            viewButton.grid(row=i, column=8)
        i +=1

#edit data and update db
def edit(id):
    global i
    print(id)
    conn = sqlite3.connect("player_record.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    id_entry.delete(0, END)
    fn_entry.delete(0, END)
    ln_entry.delete(0, END)
    bd_entry.delete(0, END)
    pos_entry.delete(0, END)
    height_entry.delete(0, END)
    weight_entry.delete(0, END)
    row = c.execute("SELECT * FROM MyPlayers WHERE playerID=%s", id)
    s = row.fetchone()
    id_entry.insert(0, s[0])
    fn_entry.insert(0, s[1])
    ln_entry.insert(0, s[2])
    bd_entry.insert(0, s[3])
    pos_entry.insert(0, s[4])
    height_entry.insert(0, s[5])
    weight_entry.insert(0, s[6])


Add the full error traceback to your question.

Some SQL libraries use %s as the value placeholder, and others use ?.

Python with sqllite need a tuple and has ? as place holder
so rewriteb your code to
row = c.execute("SELECT * FROM MyPlayers WHERE playerID=?", (id,))


that how it is define for every variable you want to replace you add a ? and then add a tuple with ypur variables in equal numbers

You were confusing string format statements (which use %s) with the SQL execute statement.  You should never use string format statements to generate SQL statements as you are opening yourself up to a major security hole.

@FrankYellin Some python SQL packages (for example MySQL) do use %s as the value placeholder.

@JohnGordon.  Ah, good to know.  But know matter what, generating a query using string formatting/interpolation is a security hole.
